# Android handle message from handler

Tags: android, handler

i implement simple media player, but i want handle my player by using handler. For example - my OnClick:

```
public void playerControls(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Play:
            if (!PlayerService.isPlay()) {
                Log.i(TAG, DeviceHelper.getMethodName() + " Media start play");
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                service.play();
                trackTitle.setText(service.getTrackTitle());
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, DeviceHelper.getMethodName() + " Media pause");
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                service.pause();
                trackTitle.setText("Paused...");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.NextTrack:
            Log.i(TAG, DeviceHelper.getMethodName() + " Next track please");
            if (PlayerService.isPlay()) {
                service.nextTrack();
                trackTitle.setText(service.getTrackTitle());
            }
            break;
        case R.id.PreviousTrack:
            Log.i(TAG, DeviceHelper.getMethodName() + " Previous track please");
            if (PlayerService.isPlay()) {
                service.previousTrack();
                trackTitle.setText(service.getTrackTitle());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And i want send message by handler, something like this:

```
case R.id.NextTrack:
        Log.i(TAG, DeviceHelper.getMethodName() + " Next track please");
        if (PlayerService.isPlay()) {
        Message m = new Message;    
        m.what = MyConstant;
        handler.sendMessage(m);
        trackTitle.setText(service.getTrackTitle());
        }
        break;
```

And handle this message in another class, where i implement my logic. But in this implementation i haven't see my message.

Could you please provide some help? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Messenger to send the message and create a public interface to handle the callback.

```
public interface MyCallbacks {
    public void handleMessage(Message m);
}
```

Then declare the messenger:

```
final Messenger mMess = new Messenger(new MyHandler));

class MyHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case i: 
            if (mCallback != null)
                mCallback.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Then wherever you want to handle this you would do:

```
public class handlingClient implements MyCallbacks {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //handles the msg here
    }
}
```